# For-Loop in VB.Net very slow, rows more than 40K

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, visual-studio-2022

Populate data in grid and then run for-loop to check row data and update the database.

Notice: If rows less than 10K then I get the output within 5-6mins and if rows more than that it will take long time. Check for 40K rows it will take 50mins approx.

Also noticed in diagnostic tools process memory  goes to 0 after 7-8mins but when start it taking 129mb.

Let suggest any other loop will be faster than for-loop or any other issue which need to be fixed.

Thanks

[image: when function start processing]

[image: Process memory down to 0]

Code:

```
  Private Sub Plan_Book()
For mRow = 1 To FGTargetRow.Rows - 1
  Dim Dm As String = Trim(FGTargetRow.get_TextMatrix(mRow, 2))
  Dim Mi As String = Trim(FGTargetRow.get_TextMatrix(mRow, 3))
  Dim mType As String = Trim(FGTargetRow.get_TextMatrix(mRow, 4))
  Dim mcT As String = Trim(FGTargetRow.get_TextMatrix(mRow, 18))
  Dim TCode As String = Trim(FGTargetRow.get_TextMatrix(mRow, 22))
  Dim PCode As String = Trim(FGTargetRow.get_TextMatrix(mRow, 21))
  Dim PlanDate As String = CDate(FGTargetRow.get_TextMatrix(mRow, 19)).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
  Dim mcShift As Double = Val(FGTargetRow.get_TextMatrix(mRow, 13))
  Dim PlanMinutes As Decimal = Val(FGTargetRow.get_TextMatrix(mRow, 23))
  Dim Buc As Integer = Trim(FGTargetRow.get_TextMatrix(mRow, 1))
  Dim ActualMins As Decimal
  Dim BookMins As Decimal
  Dim BalMins As Decimal
  Dim mcRowMax As Decimal
  Dim PrimSetup As Decimal
  Dim DSBalance As String

  mcRowMax = MacBalance(mType, mcT, PlanDate, PCode, TCode)
  DSBalance = SetBalance(mType, mcT, Dm, Mi, Buc)
  BalMins = Val(Split(DSBalance, ";")(0))
  PrimSetup = Val(Split(DSBalance, ";")(1))
  ActualMins = (mcDown * mcShift)
  BookMins = Math.Min(BalMins, ActualMins)

  If BookMins > 0 Then
    FGTargetRow.set_TextMatrix(mRow, 20, BookMins)
    Connect.GetSingleData("Execute usp_Mac_Booked '" & mType & "','" & mcT & "','" & PlanDate & "','" & PCode & "','" & TCode & "','" & BookMins & "'")
    FGTargetRow.set_TextMatrix(mRow, 27, mcT)
    Connect.GetSingleData("Execute usp_Dmix_Setup_Booked '" & mType & "','" & mcT & "','" & Dm & "','" & Mi & "','" & Buc & "','" & BookMins & "','" & PrimSetup & "'")
  End If
Next
```

End Sub

I think due to this output is delay?

Comment: Can you show us the code for the the for loop that's causing a slowdown. I assume this is a windows form DataGridView. Adding rows to a DataGridView is quite slow past 100 entries. As a rule of thumb though you want to keep the DataGridView more manageable for the user to see all the data. The next question is why a DataGridView with 40k entries?

Comment: Not using DataGridView, using C1FlexGridClassic.

Comment: If you're hitting a database (as your "Connect.GetSingleData" insinuates.....then you are dealign with RBAR : https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/what-is-rbar-how-can-i-avoid-it      you cannot get good performance hitting the database for every N thing you have.........

Comment: https://sqlstudies.com/2016/08/17/rbar-vs-batch/

Comment: https://www.devonblog.com/continuous-delivery/unlock-true-potential-of-sql-server-by-avoiding-rbar-programming/

Comment: Does the data *really* need to be stored in a control to be processed, or could it all be processed in the database in just a few seconds? It seems unlikely that someone would need to see 10,000 or more rows. Also, assuming this is WinForms and you can't do it in the database, have you tried using the [Control.SuspendLayout Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout) so the control doesn't have to do the hard work of updating its display while the processing is going on?

Comment: Oh ya the flex grid is going to be the same problem that a DataGridView has. This is a problem that can only really be fixed by re-thinking how you display the data. Is there a filter you can put on it or if you can only show 50 entries at a time and on a button event shows the next 50 entries. This would simulate a scrolling of sorts.

Comment: Yes, this is a design issue than anything else. Ask yourself the question which user is ever going to browse **10k** rows, let alone even 40k? So before populating the grid, either define a sane default, and if only limitig the data to the TOP <x> rows. Or make the user to seelect soe filters first, then query the data.

Comment: WinForm App  and Required RBR processing to calculate and plan accordingly based on output.
We tried both updating table using sql procedure and also populating data in another grid and check and update accordingly.

Comment: @Flame Nothing in the question needs to be processed row-by-row instead of the database way of doing it. If you don't have anyone available who can work out how to do that, maybe hiring a consultant would help?

Comment: Thanks, we have done it using the store procedure.

Comment: @Flame Just out of interest, how much time does it take to run the stored procedure as compared to the previous method shown in the question?

Comment: It will take 4mins 28secs